# Como sacar la asimetria en R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

hola estoy intentando sacar la asimetria en R studio pero todo me da error, Como seria el codigo base para hacerlo?, lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
   library(moments)
skewness(tv)
```

La variable tv representa las horas de tv que ven las personas de una encuesta, necesito sacar la asimetria de esa distribucion, pero me da el siguiente error...

```
Error in skewness(as.vector(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  objeto 'tv' no encontrado
```

Pero la variable tv si existe incluso asi en minuscula, alguien podria ayudarme, soy nuevo en esto, muchas gracias.

Comment: sin saber como son los datos, lo primero que se me ocurre es que no has puesto el nombre del fichero donde estan los datos. prueba con                             skewness(nombre_de_datos$tv)

Comment: muchas gracias, con eso si me da la asimetria pero me da la de todas las variables, como podria hacer para que solo me de la de la tv??

Comment: eso debería darte solo la de tv. Podrías poner un ejemplo de tus datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ejemplo mínimo creando un data frame (`df`) que contiene la variable (`tv`)

```
set.seed(12)
df = data_frame(tv = sample(1:10, 100, TRUE ))

# Variable tv

tv = df$tv

# Skewness

skewness(df$tv)
[1] 0.2775269
```

Comment: dale una explicacion para ese codito